# How does soldering affect the internal bonding between the IC die and its package?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, soldering, temperature

In other words, How does the IC fabricator solder these thin wires between the die and the pads and guarantee that the soldering iron temp (300C for example) on the IC pads won't desolder them?

[image: IC Die and wire bonds]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bond wires are not soldered to the die. They are predominantly attached via a process called gold ball bonding. It uses gold bond wires, and welds them to a gold pad on the die using a combination of heat, pressure, and ultrasonic energy. Gold melts at a much higher temperature than any soldering process, making for a solid bond to the die.

Comment: To be specific, the balls are actually [untrasonically welded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_welding) to the die, which is a form of [Solid-state welding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welding#Solid-state) (i.e. a welding technique where neither of the materials being bonded are actually heated to the point of liquefaction).